# R: incorporate link function in regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I am looking to understand how the link/family function works in R to incorporate in a regression type problem.

For example, suppose I want to program a lasso algorithm with the possibility to use a link function, how does this work?

I cannot seem to find information on how to use the family function in this way, apart from inside the glm function; however if I pass my regression method to glm, I still need to use family within my method.

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what, exactly, you want to do. Would you like to use the built-in link functions in your code? If see, see `?make.link`: "it returns a link function, an inverse link function, the derivative dmu/deta and a function for domain checking."

Comment: Yes, that is what I wish, but you have put it better. Thanks for pointing that out for me. I'll edit the post when the question crystalizes.